How to enable the service required for Word assistance feature?
I am on Windows 10, MS Office Home and Student 2021. It's just my own personal computer, no associated company.
When I attempt to access Help, I get a message that "the organization's administrator has turned off the service required to use this feature.
I have read that I can open a word doc, click on "file/account/(account privacy)manage settings", scroll down to "All connected experiences", enable those, and then restart. I did that, and restarted the entire machine. But help continues to give the same message.
I went back to "All connected experiences", and it now shows as enabled.
What can I do to enable help for this installation?



Connected experiences is NOT showing as enabled in your screenshot.

When I first found this box, the checkbox was unchecked. I checked it and saved things, then restarted the computer. Now it's checked. I thought checking it enabled "all connected experiences". Is there something else I'm supposed to be doing?

Not that I know about. I just noticed the screenshot.

ok - you said "Connected experiences is NOT showing as enabled in your screenshot." How is it not showing that it is enabled?

Sorry to have bothered you, then. It is certainly checked in the screenshot I see now. Must be my eyes.
